# How can I use checkboxes in FullCalendar to hide events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to have three checkboxes (that are checked by default) that, when unchecked, hide certain events in FullCalendar.

The events are from three separate public Google Calendars in this format:

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

```
        theme: true,
        editable: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },

        eventSources: [
        {
            url: "...",
            borderColor: 'red',
            textColor: 'black',
            editable: true,
            id: "events",
            className: "events",
        },
        {
            url: "...",
            borderColor: '#01DF3A',
            textColor: 'black',
            editable: true,
            id: "rto",
            className: "rto",
        },
        {
            url: "...",
            borderColor: 'blue',
            textColor: 'black',
            editable: true,
            id: "goals",
            className: "goals",
        },
        ],
        eventClick: function(event) {
                if (event.url) {
                    window.open(event.url);
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });

    });
```